# pandas_datareader returns an empty df from Stooq

Tags: pandas-datareader

I'm new to Python. I use PyCharm 2023.1 and pandas_datareader 0.10.0 and it was successfully getting historical stock data from Stooq up until yesterday (Apr 21, 2023) but then all my py files that get stock data from stooq stopped working.

I have many .py files that get stock data from Stooq using pandas_datareader. I logged in the morning on Friday and all of them returned empty dataframes.

Here's one simplified version I was testing:

import pandas_datareader.data as pdr

data = pdr.DataReader('AAPL', 'stooq')

print (data)

Returns the following:

Empty DataFrame

Columns: []

Index: []

Comment: That sounds like a problem with Stooq so nothing we can help you with

Comment: The problem was resolved. The issue seems to be that Stooq is not providing data to my network IP address. Could be a block. The code works using another IP address for the network and also works through VPN.